# Java: Getting arraylist into RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android

I have RecyclerView (mCourseList), that list has items and those items contain some information about different courses (course name, sum of par numbers etc primitive data). I need to get every courses (every items) their all individual set of par numbers into arraylist (mParNumbersIndividually) and include that arraylist into the recyclerview item.

This is how I make new item into that list:

```
    /** Receive primitive data from and make new item with that information **/
    mCourseList.add(new CoursesItem(getIntent().getStringExtra("COURSENAME"), "Holes:", getIntent().getStringExtra("HOLENUMBER"), "Par:", Integer.toString(parCount), R.drawable.ic_delete));
```

Now I need to add / include that arraylist (mParNumbersIndividually) into that mCourseList item, that I just created. How can I do that?

Comment: could you be more specific ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I was thinking, hope its easier now to understand where I try to go with this

Answer (score 0):

Add a new variable inside the class **CoursesItem** having the type of an array

```
  ArrayList<NewCourseItem> mParNumbersIndividually;
```

Include an extra parameter to CoursesItem constructor expecting the type array.

```
 CoursesItem(var arg1, var arg2, ..., ..., ArrayList<NewCourseItem> mParNumbersIndividually)
```

Initialize the array like every other variables in the constructor

```
 this.arg1 = arg1;
 this.mParNumbersIndividually = mParNumbersIndividually;
 //...other variables initialized
```

Create getter method for the array still inside CoursesItem object

```
  public ArrayList<NewCourseItem> getParNumbersIndividually(){
   return mParNumbersIndividually;
  }
```

Afterwards pass mParNumbersIndividually array as the new argument to CourseItem constructor.

```
 //Pass the array to CourseItem
 mCourseList.add(new CoursesItem(arg1, arg2, ..., ..., mParNumbersIndividually));
```

Then access the array anytime just like all other variables inside CoursesItem object

```
 ArrayList<NewCourseItem>  mParNumbersIndividuallyNew = cousersItems.get(i).getParNumbersIndividually();
```